# И еще о большой букве в обращении "Вы"

Tags: прописная-строчная

Хочу посоветоваться.
У меня есть свой сайт, где на главной странице я написал приветствие к посетителям. Но у меня вызвал затруднение вопрос: с какой буквы там писать местоимение "вы"? Вроде бы, это обращение к человеку, зашедшему на сайт, но, с другой, и ко всем читателям сайта. Я написал с большой, но все же сомневаюсь.
Что вы посоветуете?

Comment: Будет ли разница между следующими обращениями?

- Уважаемый посетитель сайта! Наша служба поддержки Вас (?) информирует ...

- Уважаемые посетители сайта! Наша служба поддержки вас (?) информирует ...

Comment: Думаю, можно смело выбрать один из этих вариантов. Разницы большой не вижу. Если бы было "уважаемый посетитель сайта" и "вы" со строчной, это выглядело бы странно. Есть еще вариант избегать местоимения: "Наша служба поддержки информирует о том...". Русский - не английский, где одно и тоже местоимение обязательно повторять в предложении три раза. Можно и опускать.

Comment: @gecube, будет.
Первое - дурной тон. Уважения не выказывает, что бы там ни говорили, а вот претезий на этакое панибратство - сколько угодно.

Comment: Как же хорошо в английском: одно *you* на все случаи жизни! И никакой дифференциации! Ни тыканья, никаких споров! Аж завидно.

Comment: Зато у них есть проблема с третьим лицом: have и has, do и does, а иногда просто -s на конце слова.

Comment: >Как же хорошо в английском: одно you на все случаи жизни! И никакой дифференциации! Ни тыканья, никаких споров! Аж завидно.

На самом деле это совсем не так. Этикет английского письма сто очков вперёд русскому даст. У нас просто все формы упразднили большевики, а англичане блюдут традиции. Например, обращение по имени примерно соответствует нашему переходу на ты. Но только - примерно. 

Но я не об этом. Различия между ты и вы все-таки есть, несмотря на все фразы в учебниках. Они в формах yourself и yourselves. Знающие английский - поймут.

Comment: >Зато у них есть проблема с третьим лицом: have и has, do и does, а иногда просто -s на конце слова.
У них проблем нет. Это у вас проблема с английским.

Comment: Не сомневаюсь, что и в английском есть сложности, хотелось бы углубиться, но не уверена, что это уместно на данном форуме. Просто попыталась сравнить местоимение "вы", очень часто употребляемое в обоих языках. Все же возвратные yourself и yourselves не так часто встречаются, как you.

Comment: Да, не так часто. Кроме того, с ними нет никаких проблем. Всё предельно однозначно: один вариант для единственного числа, другой - для множественного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логика логикой, а эмоции часто берут верх. Мне кажется, прописной буквой уж точно никого не обидишь. Почему бы не проявить уважение таким образом к каждому посетителю сайта? Ведь каждое новое посещение добавляет рейтинг. А *вы* со строчной стоит писать, если автор явно обращается к группе людей (студентов, филологов, строителей...), когда их что-либо объединяет. И ведь на сайт люди "ходят" не группой, а по одному. Может быть, *Вы* выглядит немного лестно, но почему нет? По-моему, это приятнее, когда к тебе обращаются лично, чем как к одному из толпы. И не важно, что никто друг друга не видит в глаза.

Comment: Меня бы очень обидели.
Потому, что нпереходите на личности тогда, когда обстаглвка к этому совершенно не обязывает.
И добро бы меня одного...
Я уже приводил ссылку на Артемия Лебедева. С которым я не согласен в обосновании, но полностью разделяю тезисно. "Вы" здесь не место.

Comment: Может, я иногда с чем-то не согласна, критикую чье-то мнение, но только мнение, а кого-то лично - Боже упаси. Считаю, что это отлично, когда есть разные взгляды, ведь в споре рождается истина. Раньше я тоже исправляла "Вы" на "вы" в своей работе (благодаря Лебедеву), но теперь передумала. Может, передумаю снова - не знаю.

Comment: Лебедев - не авторитет, тут я согласен. 
Но исправлять в угоду спору, в котором сдохла истина, - тоже не стоит.
Ну какую истину можно найти, если у одной стороны все аргументы либо "не смей со мной спорить", либо "поищите в интернете". Ничего конкретного, кроме личного мнения этакого руководителя, который исправляет "согласно приказу" на "согласно приказа" потому, что начальство так говорит, и "бестоварный" на "безтоварный" потому, что "бестоварный" нет в словаре.

Comment: @behemothus Штампик внизу документа видите? Будете смеяться, но именно этот пустячок делает письмо официальным ответом.

Comment: @Shamov, фигу видите? Так вот она не делает ваше мнение истинным.
В лучшем случае - официальным ответом Иванова и Сафоновой (что, кстати, тоже можно оспорить). Но никак не ИРЯ РАН. 

Будете смеяться, но вы абсолютно не понимаете значения терминов личный, официальный и проч.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Оно очень важно для нас.

Comment: Еще один момент. @behemotus, Вы комментируете написанное выше: "У них проблем нет. Это у вас проблема с английским." Вот не совсем понятно, кого Вы имеете ввиду, ведь слово "вас" написано со строчной и по поводу трудностей английского высказался более чем один собеседник. Ну я-то не отрицаю, что не имею проблем с англ., и не обижусь, но дело принципа: в полилоге можно легко запутаться, к кому обращение, так как нет дифференциации Вас и вас (единственное число или множественное).

Comment: Он там меня процитировал явным образом. Кроме того, по общему контексту понятно, что всё плохое - это про меня. Но я соглашусь с тем, что в общем случае формат полилога создаёт некоторые трудности. Лично я, когда пишу, стараюсь сделать всё для того, чтобы быть правильно понятым. Поэтому в случае обращения к нескольким лицам использую вместо "вы" более сложные конструкции (напр. "никто из вас" или "все вы").

Answer (score 2):

В данной ситуации правила предписывают писать обращение с маленькой буквы. Ведь она не подпадает ни под одно из исключений, в которых нужно писать с большой. Приветствие к посетителям сайта не является ни личным письмом (это публичное обращение), ни анкетой, ни официальным документом (т.е. текстом, адресованным официальному лицу, именуемому по названию должности).

В интернет-архиве существует копия [официального ответа Института русского языка](http://web.archive.org/web/20081022205917/www.yandex.ru/info/you_full.html), содержащего ответ ровно на этот самый вопрос.

**UPD:** Желающие могут открыть статью "Вы" на Википедии и перейти по ссылке оттуда. Она там находится среди примечаний.

Comment: Хотя ответ по сути и приаввильный, но минус вам - за очередную ложь. 
Ссылки здесь ставятся без проблем. Только Вы сам этот ответ видели по "ссылке из вики"? Она ведет в никуда, как и многое там.
Зато есть ответ Грамоты.

Comment: Вопрос № 238313     
...  
Можно ли употреблять в статье-интервью обращение к собеседнику на "вы" со строчной? или это грубая ошибка и "Вы" должно быть исключительно с прописной?  
Спасибо.  
bertylo
Ответ справочной службы русского языка  
Правило о написании Вы с прописной буквы при вежливом обращении к одному лицу не является строго обязательным и применяется по желанию пишущего. Написание вы со строчной – вовсе не ошибка (и уж тем более не грубая). Обращение на вы  само по себе является признаком уважительного отношения к собеседнику.  
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_320552

Comment: @behemothus Не выставляйте себя большим идиотом, чем являетесь в действительности.

1. Если я сказал, что данная конкретная ссылка не ставится, то значит она и правда не ставится.
2. Если вы не можете правильно открыть ссылку из вики, то это не значит, что она ведёт в никуда.

Comment: Как ставится минус в комментарии? Я могу поставить только "нравится". А мне очень НЕ нравится предыдущий комментарий. Минус!  Shamov, вам ваше уважение на форуме еще заслужить надо, а behemothus мы знаем и уважаем, о чем свидетельствует самый высокий рейтинг. И грубить у нас не принято!

Comment: У него такой высокий рейтинг только потому, что нельзя минусовать комментарии. Именно в них он наиболее ярко проявляет себя в качестве тролля. Он вообще слегка ошибся сайтом. Думает, что этот сайт предназначен для общения и ведения дискуссий в комментариях, что это не база знаний, а обычный интернет-форум. Грубить я тоже не люблю. Но в данном случае мне приходится это делать. У моей грубости есть вполне конкретная цель. Я хочу добиться того, чтобы этот человек либо вообще не комментировал мои ответы, либо комментировал только в тех случаях, когда есть что сказать по существу.

Comment: Милейший, у меня высокий рейтинг потому, что я на этом форуме почти с первого дня и старался соблюдать правила и этикет околонаучного общения. Чего и вам желаю.   
Но главное - потому, что давал ответы по существу. И когда был неправ - признавал и благодарил, а не возводил напраслину на тех, кто усомнился в моей святости.  

Я комментировал и буду комментировать ваши посты именно потому, что мне есть что сказать и по существу, и по поводу ваших постоянных нарушений этики общения в интернете. Хотя бы с той же ссылкой в никуда.

Comment: По поводу ссылки из Вики. 
Дайте ссылку на истоник, если вы его дейтсивтельно читали.  
А ссылаться на то, что кто-то не может открыть вашу битую ссылку, - это так знакомо... ;)

Comment: Ничего не могу сказать про то, что было раньше, но к данному моменту вы определённо утратили способность давать ответы по существу. Об этом я могу судить не только по своим вопросам, но и по вопросам других участников. Вы постоянно вступаете в неуместные дискуссии. И даже ограничения в движке, специально сделанные для предотвращения этого, вас не останавливают.

Comment: Ссылка находится там, где я и описал. В одном из примечаний к статье на Вики. Только не первая, а следующая. На ней написано "Архивировано".

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума, пожалуйста, избегайте личных замечаний.

Comment: @behemothus, по-моему Вы слишком развоевались. Подключите свое чувство юмора. Ну не нравится Вам @Shamov - так не отвечайте на его тексты. Как-то даже грустно Вас в последнее время читать. Успокойтесь, не открывайте форум пару дней - глядишь, собеседники перестанут казаться Вам такими противными...

Comment: @behemothus, то, что Вы пишете по существу вопроса - интересно и полезно. Только нежелательно разбрасывать вокруг так много "фиг". Перечитайте свои комментарии и посмотрите: сколько из них по делу, а сколько - личных. Мы Вас любим и уважаем, пожалуйста, не разочаровывайте нас. ((

Answer (score 1):

Читать Ваше обращение будет не толпа, а индивидуально каждый посетитель сайта, поэтому обращение "Вы" вполне оправданно.

Answer (score 1):

Это как раз типичный и часто приводимый пример неправильного употребления "Вы" при неличном обращении. На самом деле здесь рекомендуется писать "вы", со строчной буквы. Поскольку обращение идет не к каждому конкретному посетителю, которого пишущий не знает.

Последнее время, правда, наметилась теденция писать "Вы" всюду, где только можно, по принципу "рука не отсохнет", причем это активно (чтобы не сказать "агрессивно") насаждается. Но лично мне это представляется совершенно неправильнм и нелогичным. "Вы" с загланой - знак уважения к конкретному лицу, как его можно выказывать не зная заранее, кто читать будет, - ума не приложу.

> Ссылка находится там, где я и описал. В одном из примечаний к статье на Вики. Только не первая, а следующая. На ней написано "Архивировано".
> (Shamov)

Ну так дайте прямую ссылку на источник, если вы его действительно читали.
Хватит уже врать, я проверял все варианты найти что-либо.
И про невставляющиеся ссылки - из той же серии. 
За полгода никто не жаловался.

Shamov, [это](http://web.archive.org/web/20081022205917/www.yandex.ru/info/you_full.html) что ли? За вас работу делаю.
Ну и что тут надо читать? Да, уважаемая мной лично Юлия Александровна Сафонова (ex-редактор [gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru)) и неизвестный мне господин Иванов высказали свое мнение. Ни о каком официальном ответе ИРЯ речи не идёт. 
Кстати, тоже самое - в ответах грамоты. И именно этот пункт я поставил под сомнение, поскольку он противоречит общей концепции обращаться в неличных (не адресованных конкретной личности) сообщениях со строчной.

Решительно ничего не добавляет к сказанному. Подозреваю, что именно поэтому с таким скрипом и пришлось вытягивать источник.

Интересно, кстати, было бы услышать мнение Юлии Алексанлровны сейчас, спустя двенадцать лет, когда интеренет стал делом обыденным - и абсолютное большинство анкет заполняется дистанционно.

Что остаётся? Мильчин 1985 г. и построенный на нем некий ГОСТ тоже эпохи раннего интернета. Никто более об анкетах как исключении из общего правила "неличное - со строчной" не упоминает. Не знаю, насколько это достаточный аргумент... Отдаёт номенклатурными указивками 30-х годов...

Всё было бы хорошо, если бы не именно это вопиющее исключение... Чем анкета отличается от памятки в гостинице? "О пожаре Вы можете сообщить в скорую помощь".

> [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus), по-моему Вы слишком развоевались. Подключите свое чувство юмора. Ну не нравится Вам [[@Shamov](/users/1139/shamov)](/users/1139/shamov) - так не отвечайте на его тексты. Как-то даже грустно Вас в последнее время читать. Успокойтесь, не открывайте форум пару дней - глядишь, собеседники перестанут казаться Вам такими противными...

Мне глубоко наплевать на личность г-на Shamov'a, но не стоит валить все сч больной головы на здоровую. Я отвечаю не на его тектсы, а на то, на что мне есть что ответить. 
Перефразируя вас, грустно читать мои тектсы - не читайте. Пусть флудеру грустно будет. Он-то мимо не пройдёт.

Comment: Прямая ссылка есть в моём ответе. Но она открывается неправильно. Попробуйте взять прямую ссылку из Вики и поставить её.

Comment: Упс! Ситуация изменилась. @ХэшКод всё исправил. Теперь ссылка открывается.

Comment: У меня по-прежнему ничего не открывается. Уточню - За исключением первой страницы некоего архива с непонятного содержания.

Так что пожелание увидеть таки прямую ссылку остаётся в силе.
Иначе останусь при своём мнении, что Вы сам статью эту не читали.

Comment: Господи! Ну, как же можно быть таким тупым! Я имею в виду не вашу неспособность открыть ссылку, а вашу угрозу остаться при своём мнений. Ей богу! Это очень страшно! :)
На первом экране архива надо немного подождать и произойдёт автоматическая переадресация. Кроме того, там справа внизу есть специальная ссылка для нетерпеливых.

Comment: Вас, кажется, просили не преходить на личности?
Повторяю, вы в состоянии, дать **прямую** ссылку или будете продлжать перекладывать с больной головы на здоровую?  
Или вам эта ситуация нужна только затем, чтобы безнаказанно хамить оппоненту?

Comment: Более прямую ссылку дать нельзя. Но @Хэшкод всё исправил. Она теперь открывается.

Comment: Да ладно вам, ничего там не изменилось.
Ну коль вам непременно нужно было воздать хвалу администратору, прокмментируете, наконец, суть столь важного для вас документа? 
Я не вижу причин ни называть его официальным ответом ИРЯ, ни тем более следовать его рекомендациям. О чем и написал.